# what-source (part of what-utils) returns package name two times

Tags: command-line, package-management, deb, source-packages

On my Ubuntu 14.04.2, `what-source` returns two times the package name for *some* packages, e.g.

```
~$ what-source openssl
openssl
openssl
```

or

```
~$ what-source firefox
firefox
firefox
```

Is this normal behavior?

The example from the manual [here](http://manned.org/what-source.1) returns only one (same for my machine: only one name returned):

```
~$ what-source sl
sl
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/what-source.1) says, `what-source` is a simple wrapper for `apt-cache show | grep`. The actual code is:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# [....]
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

apt-cache show "$1" | grep "^Filename:" | sed -e "s:\(.*\)/\(.*\)/\(.*\)/\(.*\)/.*:\4:"
```

`apt-cache show` will show the description for each version of the software available in the repositories. For example:

```
$ apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

There are two versions available in three repositories, and `apt-cache` will show descriptions of these two versions:

```
$ apt-cache show firefox | grep -i -e version -e filename
Version: 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Filename: pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
Version: 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2
Filename: pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_28.0+build2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

So, yes, the behaviour is perfectly normal.